# Lucene.net not returning search results

Tags: .net, lucene, lucene.net

I've 8 text files containing about 5 million rows of similar encoded data-

> -Allocating path TRNS_Legacy_773 of type TRNS_Legacy to DEV\svcInformational_1_7 via document #12478901.  There are now  35
>   such paths with 1 in use
>
> -Msg (len:482) sent on TRNS_Legacy_773 :'FETCHIT IMG 771777777291;1;577;17;SAI13761671;1;577;IMG 771777771191;1;1;15;707747
>   261174767;23;19;07;187;314;315;316;318;327;486;480;670;230;238;239;247;279;427;421;109;512;924;935;936;IMG
>   771777777501;1;1;15;707747
>   261174767;9;5;64;65;66;01;06;122;184;940;IMG
>   771777777641;1;1;15;82748/4141541
>   ;9;245;246;249;248;244;243;242;241;620;IMG 771777771321;1;1;15;707747
>   261174767;29;4;19;25;20;62;64;65;66;07;87;81;82;122;187;194;241;245;370;315;316;319;579;517;512;525;587;027;935;936;'
>
> -Message rcvd and correlated on TRNS_Legacy_773, correlator was 'IAS1376167'. Response time was 31ms.

I've indexed the files with lucene.net standard analyser. When I try to search for a substring such as "4141541" or "FETCHIT", the search returns 0 results. I've used Luke and can see that data is present in the index. I am able to search using the line number but not using the text. Can someone please help me out?

I've tried using wildcard searches, tried different queries, tried different analysers, kept my text as tokenized as well as untokenized but it either returns 0 results or returns only 1 or 2 lines even though there should be 1000s of lines returned.

```
private Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
```

Building Index-

```
public void BuildIndex(string item)
    {

        string indexPath = string.Format(baseIndexPath, item);
        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(indexPath))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.Delete(indexPath, true);
        }

        luceneIndexDirectory = FSDirectory.GetDirectory(indexPath);
        writer = new IndexWriter(indexPath, analyzer, true);
        //writer = new IndexWriter(luceneIndexDirectory, analyzer, true);

        string file = string.Format(@"LogFile.txt");
        string line=string.Empty;
        int count = 0;
        StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(file);
        while ((line = fileReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            count++;
            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.Add(new Field("LineNumber", count.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED));
            doc.Add(new Field("LineText", line, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED));

            writer.AddDocument(doc);
        }
        writer.Optimize();
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
        luceneIndexDirectory.Close();
    }
```

public IEnumerable Search(string searchTerm)
        {

```
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(luceneIndexDirectory);
        QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("LineText", analyzer);
        TermQuery tQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("LineText",searchTerm));
        Query query = parser.Parse(searchTerm);
        Hits hitsFound = searcher.Search(query); //returns 0 results
        hitsFound = searcher.Search(tQuery); //returns 0 results
        List<SampleDataFileRow> results = new List<SampleDataFileRow>();
        SampleDataFileRow sampleDataFileRow = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < hitsFound.Length(); i++)
        {
            sampleDataFileRow = new SampleDataFileRow();
            Document doc = hitsFound.Doc(i);
            sampleDataFileRow.LineNumber = int.Parse(doc.Get("LineNumber"));
            sampleDataFileRow.LineText = doc.Get("LineText");


            results.Add(sampleDataFileRow);
        }

        return results.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Please show which Analyzer you are using for creating the index and which Analyzer is used for searching the index.

Comment: have added to the code above. private Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the issue is how StandardAnalyzer is breaking up the tokens.  When you use Luke I suspect you don't see `4141541`  or `FETCHIT` as individual tokens in the `LineText` terms and they need to be if you want to search on those value and get a result.

Comment: Thanks but how do I fix it then?

Comment: Can you confirm that in Luke you don't see `4141541` or `FETCHIT` as individual tokens?